# Want to show one highest scorer details grouped by every month

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table of data 
DB table look like

```
   id   |   name   |  userid  |  score   |      date      |
   ------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |   john   |    4     |   233    |  2014-02-02 
    2   |   mary   |    5     |  1256    |  2013-02-05  
    3   |   john   |    6     |   100    |  2013-03-08 
    4   |   elvis  |    7     |   123    |  2013-03-04 
    5   |   john   |    2     |   1234   |  2013-03-02
```

now i want to show one highest scorer details of every month.my retrieve data output will be json format

currently my query output show

```
"monthly_winners":[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "score":"233",
        "month":"Feb"
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
        "score":"100",
        "month":"Mar"
    }
],
```

But It will be

```
"monthly_winners":[
    {
        "id":"2",
        "score":"1256",
        "month":"Feb"
    },
    {
        "id":"5",
        "score":"1234",
        "month":"Mar"
    }
],
```

i cant understand whats wrong in my query

my query is

```
SELECT id,score, DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%b' ) AS month FROM `winner`  GROUP BY month ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: The sample data you provided only shows a single entry for March, and it is the one returned in your first resultset. Can you explain the logic of how you make the row with ID = 5 into March's monthly winner? It seems to have a January date.

Comment: Your current query is using GROUP BY on the month, and returning the id and score. It does not specify which rows id and score for a month will be returned, and the row that MySQL choses to use for those values is undefined.

Comment: sorry its my writing mistake i already rewrite it @OllieJones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m')yearmonth
            , MAX(score) max_score 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m')
     ) y
    ON y.yearmonth = DATE_FORMAT(x.date,'%Y%m')
   AND y.max_score = x.score;
```

Comment: Beat me to it. The only issue is which winner to return if 2 of them share the same max score in a month.

Answer (score 0):

Just for interest and following up on the answer by Strawberry (which probably covers your requirements), the following should give you consistently a single matching id / name if 2 people both share the same highest score for a month (I have just randomly chosen to get the details for the user with the highest id).

```
SELECT winner.id, winner.score, DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y%m' ) AS `month`
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y%m' ) AS aMonth, MAX(score) AS max_score
    FROM winner
    GROUP BY aMonth
) Sub1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y%m' ) AS aMonth, score, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM winner
    GROUP BY aMonth, score
) Sub2
ON Sub2.score = Sub1.max_score
AND Sub2.aMonth = Sub1.aMonth
INNER JOIN winner
ON winner.score = Sub1.max_score
AND DATE_FORMAT(winner.`date`,'%Y%m' ) = Sub1.aMonth
AND winner.id = Sub2.max_id
```